# BOOTMGR is compressed Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, bootmgr

This is my first question to "superuser", hope you guys help me.

I have Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise installed in my system, by mistake I clicked the "Compress disk" of my C drive.

Now when I am restarting, I met a message at start up that "BootMGR is compressed, Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart"

Its been 2 days I am searching every where to solve the problem, but all I found only for Vista and windows 7 only.

Can any one help?

Comment: Have you tried booting from the OS disk and using the various startup repair options?  For 2008, most of those instructions you're finding should still apply -- with a little modification.  Like having to manually run StartRep.exe for example.   What have you tired already (aside from searching)? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I insert the Windows server 2008 disk in CD-Rom and got repair computer screen, then a window open having 3 choices (Command prompt, Disk Image and Hardware recovery) Now what to do? Because I don't have Image for it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) when selecting the installation, then press "Load Drivers" (Instead of "Next") and use the mini Windows Explorer to right-click the boot-drive click properties and deselect "Compress this Drive" and choose Apply to sub-folders and files.

It worked for me.